# Visual Studio web performance test does not download images

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing

**Test tool:** Visual Studio web performance test.

I am creating load test for an ecommerce website, which contains lots of product images. While recording the web test it just records the page reqeust/response time and not the image download time. So on testing page load time always shows lower than what it actually is. Even fiddler gives proper page time as it checks for every request including image load.

I have tried setting parse dependent request as true also but still not working.

**Q:** How do i test the image download time along with page load time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio web performance tests do process dependent requests but they do not process Javascript and other active components. Many web pages describe their images etc via a mix of Javascript, XML, Json and so on. None of this will be processed by a web test. If the images etc are described by these non-html pieces then the test will need to take special action to load them. For example, by writing a plugin that reads the relevant image descriptions from a response and generating dependent requests to load them. The mechanisms for doing this are highly dependent on the actual files of the website.